# How to use ZAP to scan web application hosted in embedded browser control

Tags: cefsharp, zap

I have a web application (developed in Angular4) **hosted with embedded web browser** that is Chromium Web Browser Control (CefSharp) in a desktop application.

The web application is **tightly coupled with host desktop application** hence cannot be run it on browser independently.

Considering the scenario, Can I automate scanning or by any means perform scanning manually with ZAP API tool ?

Answer (score 1):

After spending few minutes I realized that ZAP is independent of browser type. It  supports any type of browser (including embedded one).

What it needs to read websites  is proxy set up.

I just set up proxy to “CefSettings” while initializing the app.

Note: ZAP server is running on "localhost:8081".

```
var cfsettings = new CefSettings();
cfsettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", "localhost:8081");

Cef.Initialize(cfsettings);
browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
```